# Gathering problem

Tags: combinatorics

I thought I had a proper solution for the following problem, but my teacher said it's wrong. I have no idea/clue how to do it in a different, correct way.

*There gathered n people in a room. At the beginning of this meeting every person had exactly 3 friends among the rest in the room. During the meeting some people met each other. When the meeting ended, every person had exactly 4 friends among the rest. Find all n numbers for which this situation is possible (we assume, that if person A knows person B, then person B knows person A).*

Best regards,

Tom.

Comment: Oh then by all means show us your solution.

Comment: Or at least tell us what you think the solution is for a total of $4, 5, 6$ and $7$ people.

Comment: @SimonS: You have a solution for 7 people? Really?

Comment: As described the "A knows B" relation (being symmetric and irreflexive) determines an undirected simple graph.  The problem concerns adding edges to a regular graph of degree 3 to obtain one of degree 4.

Comment: @SimonS My incorrect solution is n=8k, where k is natural. 
The proper solution is: n should be at least 6 and even, but I can't understand why

Comment: @user21820, I should say: explain why it is or is not possible in each of those cases.

Comment: I drew a graph and now I see why it's for n (even), that are bigger or equal to 6, but I can't **write** a proper solution.

Comment: Okay I'll write you a proof sketch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that the initial graph is 3-regular, and so $3n = 2m$ where $n$ is the number of vertices and $m$ is the number of edges (acquaintances). Thus $n$ is even. Clearly $n > 4$ because $4$ is too few to have $4$ acquaintances. Now the problem is to find a solution for any even $n$ that is at least $6$.

The trick is to find a solution for each $n$ in $(6,8,10)$, because you can combine them to get a solution for any larger $n$, because $6+6k = (k+1)(6)$ and $6+6k+2 = k(6)+8$ and $6+6k+4 = k(6)+10$, for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$. It should not be too hard to find solutions for the three base cases with some trial and error.

Comment: I pretty much understand your solution, but let's take for 8:
why is that $$6k+8$$?

Comment: @TomDavies92: I don't quite get your question. There are only 3 cases for even numbers greater or equal to 6, each of which can be written as a natural number times 6 plus either 6 or 8 or 10. My natural numbers include 0.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of diagrams to begin to build intuition, this is the kind of thing I was thinking about, showing regular graphs for low integers. (A regular graph being a graph where every vertex has an equal local degree, i.e., number of edges.) You can see there are no solutions for $n < 6$ or for $n = 7$.

[image]

This is an intriguing problem. Doing some research I was surprised to find that we have no closed formula for the number of regular graphs of $n$ vertices with $m$ edges, just an [asymptotic one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77730/how-many-p-regular-graphs-with-n-vertices-are-there).

Comment: For $n=6$, take the second 3-regular one, and add three of the sides of the hexagon to it.

Comment: I literally just saw that as well. Thanks.